# QuickSort in c++

Tags: c++, quicksort

I'm trying to get quicksort working to sort an array of 7000 strings into alphabetical order, but all i'm getting is a blank output file. It works fine with my bubblesort method, but not with this. I'm sure it's an obvious mistake, but i can't pin-point it.

```
void ArrayStorage::quicksort(int first, int last, string list[])
{
        int middle, p, index;
    string temp, partition;
    if (first < last)
    {  
            middle = int(first + last)/2;
            temp = list[middle];
            list[middle] = list[first];
            list[first] = temp;
            partition = list[first];
            p = first;
            for (index = first + 1; index <= last; index++)
            {
                    if(list[index] < partition)
                    {
                            p = p + 1;
                            temp = list[index];
                            list[index] = list[p];
                            list[p] = temp;
                    }  
            }  
            temp = list[first];
            list[first] = list[p];
            list[p] = temp;
            quicksort(first, p - 1, list);
            quicksort(p + 1, last, list);
    }
}
```

I call the method like this:

```
  quicksort(0,GetSize() -1,namesArray);
```

Comment: Do you have access to a debugger? Knowing how to use a debugger is a valuable skill and you'd probably already have your answer if you used one.

Comment: If this is a homework, please tag it as such. If not, just use `std::sort`.

Comment: Simply have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Comment: If you're truly getting "a blank output file" then something may be wrong in other code besides what you've provided here. Can you show us the code that's calling your sorting routine? When it works with a bubblesort, is that with the exact same code except that it calls `bubblesort` instead of `quicksort`?

Comment: Yeah basically my code looks like
    //bubbleSort();
      quicksort(0,GetSize() -1,namesArray);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using the built in quicksort?:

std::sort(&namesArray[0], &namesArray[GetSize()]);

Comment: Yeah sorry, i should have said, i'm comparing std sort and my own sort for my assignment, because we're just doing about performance and stuff using parasoft and profiling

Comment: then replace                             temp = list[index];
                            list[index] = list[p];
                            list[p] = temp; with std::swap(list[index], list[p]);

Comment: Thanks Viktor, that sped my quick sort up by 15ms, after i managed to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Well as the principle in each loop of quick sort is to make the temp variable in the position that all elements less than it are put left to temp and greater ones on the right. So that must be a loop contains both rightwards iteration to search if there's any number greater than temp and leftwards vice versa. If there is, put the current content to the other side then iterating from the other side until the overall iteration of the list. After the loop all elements less than temp should be on the left while greater ones on right.

```
temp = list[first];
int f = first, l = last;
while (f < l)
{
    while ((f <= l) && (list[l] < temp)) l--;
    if (f <= l)
    {
        list[f] = list[l];
        f++;
    }
    while ((f <= l) && (list[f] > temp)) f++;
    if (f <= l)
    {
        list[l] = list[f];
        l--;
    }
}
```

This piece of code should work.(I don't have the compiler on this computer) If it does, try to invoke the function itself recursively.

In addition there's an advice. As many people's recommended you, trying debug and solve the problem yourself.

Hope it helps

Comment: I'm trying to debug it, but in visual studio it keeps jumping into assembly code, and that just blows my mind. It's taking the names and everything in, it's almost as if it's just not outputting anything. But it should be and as far as i know the code makes sense. :s

Comment: @Rhys Then one of two things, either you're not compiling with debug symbols or else you're entering into a std function. Make sure you're compiling everything in debug mode, and don't descend into a function unless you wrote it (step over vs step into).